# Multiple Choice Questionnaire Using Checkboxes and Computed Properties in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Hi there SO community,

I'm new to development and have just recently begun learning Ember.js.  As part of the Ember-Rails app that I'm building, I need to create a multi-step, multiple choice questionnaire.  I've been stuck on a particular issue which I have not been able to find a solution for online.

You see, I have created a computed property, responseOptions, in my Questions1Controller.  responseOptions is an array of multiple choice responses to the given question.  Each question is a record in a questions table, and each multiple choice response is represented by a column on the questions table.  I created the computed property responseOptions in order to display an array of checkboxes.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot pass the value of the selected array element, represented by a checked checkbox, to the Questions1Controller in order to create a new answer record.  I am able to access the other properties of my questions records in the Questions1Controller, just not the computed property.  I have included my Questions1Controller, along with the relevant template, below:

Questions1Controller:

```
RailsCharts.Questions1Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

actions: {
    createAnswer: function(){
        var user_id = 5;
        var question_id = this.get('hard_coded_id');
        var selected_response = this.get('selected_answer');
        var newAnswer = this.store.createRecord('answer', {
            userId: user_id,
            questionId: question_id,
            answer: selected_response
        });

        newAnswer.save();
    }
},

responseOptions: function () {
    var option1Val = this.get('option_1');
    var option2Val = this.get('option_2');
    var option3Val = this.get('option_3');
    var option4Val = this.get('option_4');
    var option5Val = this.get('option_5');

    var arryOfOptions = [option1Val, option2Val, option3Val, option4Val, option5Val];
    var arryOfOptionsFiltered = [];

    for (var i=0; i<arryOfOptions.length; i++){
        arryOfOptions[i] !== null && arryOfOptionsFiltered.push(arryOfOptions[i]);
    } 

    return arryOfOptionsFiltered;
}.property('arryOfOptionsFiltered.@each')

});
```

Questions/1 Template:

```
<h1>Question 1</h1>
<div class='form-group'>
<div class='wording'>
    {{wording}}
</div>
<hr>
<div class='answer'>
    {{#each responseOptions}}
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            {{input type='checkbox' checked=selected_answer}}{{this}}
        </label>
        </br>
    {{/each}}
</div>
{{outlet}}
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" {{action "createAnswer"}}>Submit</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just have one "selected_answer" be the value of the checkbox. It needs to be some kind of array to get all of the values.

An example might be having a 'selected' property on the actual option object itself. Your model might look like this (although you can add selected at other points)

```
App.Questions1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({
      option_1: Ember.Object.create({value: "x", selected: false}),
      option_2: Ember.Object.create({value: "y", selected: false}),
      option_3: Ember.Object.create({value: "z", selected: false}),
      option_4: Ember.Object.create({value: "a", selected: false}),
      option_5: Ember.Object.create({value: "b", selected: false})  
    });
  }
});
```

Then your template would be:

```
<div class='answer'>
    {{#each responseOptions}}
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            {{input type='checkbox' checked=this.selected}}{{this.value}}
        </label>
        </br>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Let me know if that helps.

JS bin for you to play with:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/masepexa/4/edit